# log4j2 Logger : how to log everything

Tags: java, log4j2

If I use :

```
  Appenders:
    File:
      name : app
      .....

  Loggers:
    Logger:
      name: com
      AppenderRef :
         ref: app
         .....
```

then this config will log everything from the "com-classes".

But what if I want to log also org.* and blah.*, i.e. what is the wildcard for logging ALL.

I'm talking about logger different than Root

Comment: "Root", however, this YAML doesn't seem to be the [Log4j2 YAML configuration syntax](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#YAML), so what configuration file is this?  It might work different from the Log4j2 config.

Comment: [Root logger](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)